# how to fix jquery mobile's header?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

when i am clicking anywhere (which does not cause change of page) Ex: `<li>`, then my header also is scrolling along with `li`,
if i am giving **data-tap-toggle="false**" then header is not hiding for input text boxes also.

what is the solution?

Comment: Please modify this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sn618jqk/ . I have included external ressources

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html), you have to specify **`data-position="fixed"`** in the tag.

Try this :

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
  <h1>Fixed Header!</h1>
</div>
```

Or in your case with menu **`<ul> <li>`** in the header (look [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html))

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="a.html">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="b.html">Friends</a></li>
        <li><a href="c.html">Albums</a></li>
        <li><a href="d.html">Emails</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And to hide header or footer when tap, do this ([link](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html)) :

```
$.mobile.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: you can see the same behavior in the last link you have given...click on body some where and then scroll the content and see that header and footer is scrolling along with the content, means not fixed that time.

Comment: click once it will scroll and click again it will be fixed

Comment: And this wasn't what you were looking for ?

Comment: You have to add data-tap-toggle="false" to the tag